# Node.js : Check entries regularly based on their timestamps

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have a Node.js backend and MSSQL as database. I do some data processing and store logs in a database table which shows which entity  is a what stage in the progress, e.g. (there are three stages each entity has to pass)

```
+----+-----------+-------+------------------------+
| id | entity_id | stage |   timestamp            |
+----+-----------+-------+------------------------+
|  1 |         1 |     1 | 2019-01-01 12:12:01    |
|  2 |         1 |     2 | 2019-01-01 12:12:10    |
|  3 |         1 |     3 | 2019-01-01 12:12:15    |
|  4 |         2 |     1 | 2019-01-01 12:14:01    |
|  5 |         2 |     2 | 2019-01-01 12:14:10 <--|
|  6 |         3 |     1 | 2019-01-01 12:24:01    |
+----+-----------+-------+------------------------+
```

As you can see in line with the arrow, the entity no. 2 did not go to stage 3. After a certain amount of time (maybe 120 seconds), these entity should be considered as faulty and this will be reported somehow.

What would be a good approach in Node.js  to check the table for those outtimed entities? Some kind of cron job which checks all lines every x seconds? That sounds rather clumsy to me.

I am looking forward to our ideas!

Comment: How exactly will they be reported? In a real time fashion? Also, I don't think you would have to check all lines as you could filter them to retrieve only the faulty ones and even use an index to improve this search. It depends on the criteria used to determine whether or not an entry is faulty.

Comment: This is for PostgreSQL / Go but I believe you could easily adapt it to SQL Server / Node http://coussej.github.io/2015/09/15/Listening-to-generic-JSON-notifications-from-PostgreSQL-in-Go/

Comment: @GabrielCosta Since faulty ones should go through the process again, real-time would be good. An entry is faulty if stage < 3 and timestamp is older than e.g. x seconds. The x is configurable.

Comment: @Ruan Thanks, I will have a look!

Comment: @Jominho I'm not that proficient in MSSQL procedures but I believe you could create an update trigger with a timer? This might incur a significant impact on the database, however. Using a cron job with Node would only retrieve the faulty ones and update them but this solution would also incur more database access.